# Google Drive Api To List Photos

Tags: php, api, google-drive-api

My google drive api is working nice for uploading files. But I am confused how can I list the file (especially photos) of user's drive to my website.

FYI: To download and listing I have copied the MediaFileUpload.php and created a new file named MediaFileDownload.php and then renamed all its function from %upload% to %download%.

Below is my code:

Index.php

```
    <?php
    /*
     * Copyright 2011 Google Inc.
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     * You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     * limitations under the License.
     */

    include_once "templates/base.php";
    session_start();

    set_include_path("src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
    require_once 'Google/Client.php';
    require_once 'Google/Http/MediaFileDownload.php';
    require_once 'Google/Service/Drive.php';

    /************************************************
      ATTENTION: Fill in these values! Make sure
      the redirect URI is to this page, e.g:
      http://localhost:8080/fileupload.php
     ************************************************/
    $client_id = 'Your_Client_Id';
    $client_secret = 'Your_Client_Secret';
    $redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/MyApi/Google-Drive';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($client_id);
    $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
    $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
      unset($_SESSION['download_token']);
    }

    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
      $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
      $_SESSION['download_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
      $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
      header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['download_token']) && $_SESSION['download_token']) {
      $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['download_token']);
      if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        unset($_SESSION['download_token']);
      }
    } else {
      $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    }

    /********************************************************
      If we're signed in then lets try to download our file.
     ********************************************************/
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    // This is downloading a file directly, with no metadata associated.
    echo "The code is being executed till Line No. 67.";
    /**************************************************************
    **     -----This comment is created by Ashish Shah-----     **
    ** The whole code is working if the user is not logged in.  **
    ** After user loggs in, Nothing is being displayed after    **
    ** this block.                                              **
    **************************************************************
    ** The problem is in Line No.76 to Line No.79               **
    **************************************************************/
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $result = $service->files->list(
        $file,
        array('downloadType' => 'media')
    );
}

    echo pageHeader("File Download - Downloading a Photo");
    if (
        $client_id == '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>'
        || $client_secret == '<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>'
        || $redirect_uri == '<YOUR_REDIRECT_URI>') {
      echo missingClientSecretsWarning();
    }
    ?>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="request">
        <?php if (isset($authUrl)): ?>
          <a class='login' href='<?php echo $authUrl; ?>'>Connect Me!</a>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>

      <?php if (isset($result) && $result): ?>
        <div class="shortened">
          <?php var_dump($result->title); ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    echo pageFooter(__FILE__);
    ?>
```

MediaFileDownload.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright 2012 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Exception.php';
require_once 'Google/Http/Request.php';
require_once 'Google/Http/REST.php';
require_once 'Google/Utils.php';

/**
 * @author Chirag Shah <chirags@google.com>
 *
 */
class Google_Http_MediaFileDownload
{
  const DOWNLOAD_MEDIA_TYPE = 'media';
  const UPLOAD_RESUMABLE_TYPE = 'resumable';

  /** @var string $mimeType */
  private $mimeType;

  /** @var string $data */
  private $data;

  /** @var bool $resumable */
  private $resumable;

  /** @var int $chunkSize */
  private $chunkSize;

  /** @var int $size */
  private $size;

  /** @var string $resumeUri */
  private $resumeUri;

  /** @var int $progress */
  private $progress;

  /** @var Google_Client */
  private $client;

  /** @var Google_Http_Request */
  private $request;

  /** @var string */
  private $boundary;

  /**
   * Result code from last HTTP call
   * @var int
   */
  private $httpResultCode;

  /**
   * @param $mimeType string
   * @param $data string The bytes you want to upload.
   * @param $resumable bool
   * @param bool $chunkSize File will be uploaded in chunks of this many bytes.
   * only used if resumable=True
   */
  public function __construct(
      Google_Client $client,
      Google_Http_Request $request,
      $mimeType,
      $data,
      $resumable = false,
      $chunkSize = false,
      $boundary = false
  ) {
    $this->client = $client;
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->mimeType = $mimeType;
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->size = strlen($this->data);
    $this->resumable = $resumable;
    if (!$chunkSize) {
      $chunkSize = 256 * 1024;
    }
    $this->chunkSize = $chunkSize;
    $this->progress = 0;
    $this->boundary = $boundary;

    // Process Media Request
    $this->process();
  }

  /**
   * Set the size of the file that is being uploaded.
   * @param $size - int file size in bytes
   */
  public function setFileSize($size)
  {
    $this->size = $size;
  }

  /**
   * Return the progress on the upload
   * @return int progress in bytes uploaded.
   */
  public function getProgress()
  {
    return $this->progress;
  }

  /**
   * Return the HTTP result code from the last call made.
   * @return int code
   */
  public function getHttpResultCode()
  {
    return $this->httpResultCode;
  }

  /**
   * Send the next part of the file to upload.
   * @param [$chunk] the next set of bytes to send. If false will used $data passed
   * at construct time.
   */
  public function nextChunk($chunk = false)
  {
    if (false == $this->resumeUri) {
      $this->resumeUri = $this->getResumeUri();
    }

    if (false == $chunk) {
      $chunk = substr($this->data, $this->progress, $this->chunkSize);
    }

    $lastBytePos = $this->progress + strlen($chunk) - 1;
    $headers = array(
      'content-range' => "bytes $this->progress-$lastBytePos/$this->size",
      'content-type' => $this->request->getRequestHeader('content-type'),
      'content-length' => $this->chunkSize,
      'expect' => '',
    );

    $httpRequest = new Google_Http_Request(
        $this->resumeUri,
        'PUT',
        $headers,
        $chunk
    );

    if ($this->client->getClassConfig("Google_Http_Request", "enable_gzip_for_downloads")) {
      $httpRequest->enableGzip();
    } else {
      $httpRequest->disableGzip();
    }

    $response = $this->client->getIo()->makeRequest($httpRequest);
    $response->setExpectedClass($this->request->getExpectedClass());
    $code = $response->getResponseHttpCode();
    $this->httpResultCode = $code;

    if (308 == $code) {
      // Track the amount downloaded.
      $range = explode('-', $response->getResponseHeader('range'));
      $this->progress = $range[1] + 1;

      // Allow for changing download URLs.
      $location = $response->getResponseHeader('location');
      if ($location) {
        $this->resumeUri = $location;
      }

      // No problems, but upload not complete.
      return false;
    } else {
      return Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse($response);
    }
  }

  /**
   * @param $meta
   * @param $params
   * @return array|bool
   * @visible for testing
   */
  private function process()
  {
    $postBody = false;
    $contentType = false;

    $meta = $this->request->getPostBody();
    $meta = is_string($meta) ? json_decode($meta, true) : $meta;

    $downloadType = $this->getDownloadType($meta);
    $this->request->setQueryParam('downloadType', $downloadType);
    $this->transformToDownloadUrl();
    $mimeType = $this->mimeType ?
        $this->mimeType :
        $this->request->getRequestHeader('content-type');

    if (self::DOWNLOAD_RESUMABLE_TYPE == $downloadType) {
      $contentType = $mimeType;
      $postBody = is_string($meta) ? $meta : json_encode($meta);
    } else if (self::DOWNLOAD_MEDIA_TYPE == $downloadType) {
      $contentType = $mimeType;
      $postBody = $this->data;
    } else if (self::DOWNLOAD_MULTIPART_TYPE == $downloadType) {
      // This is a multipart/related upload.
      $boundary = $this->boundary ? $this->boundary : mt_rand();
      $boundary = str_replace('"', '', $boundary);
      $contentType = 'multipart/related; boundary=' . $boundary;
      $related = "--$boundary\r\n";
      $related .= "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
      $related .= "\r\n" . json_encode($meta) . "\r\n";
      $related .= "--$boundary\r\n";
      $related .= "Content-Type: $mimeType\r\n";
      $related .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
      $related .= "\r\n" . base64_encode($this->data) . "\r\n";
      $related .= "--$boundary--";
      $postBody = $related;
    }

    $this->request->setPostBody($postBody);

    if (isset($contentType) && $contentType) {
      $contentTypeHeader['content-type'] = $contentType;
      $this->request->setRequestHeaders($contentTypeHeader);
    }
  }

  private function transformToDownloadUrl()
  {
    $base = $this->request->getBaseComponent();
    $this->request->setBaseComponent($base . '/download');
  }

  /**
   * Valid download types:
   * - resumable (DOWNLOAD_RESUMABLE_TYPE)
   * - media (DOWNLOAD_MEDIA_TYPE)
   * @param $meta
   * @return string
   * @visible for testing
   */
  public function getDownloadType($meta)
  {
    if ($this->resumable) {
      return self::DOWNLOAD_RESUMABLE_TYPE;
    }

    if (false == $meta && $this->data) {
      return self::DOWNLOAD_MEDIA_TYPE;
    }

    return self::DOWNLOAD_MULTIPART_TYPE;
  }

  private function getResumeUri()
  {
    $result = null;
    $body = $this->request->getPostBody();
    if ($body) {
      $headers = array(
        'content-type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'content-length' => Google_Utils::getStrLen($body),
        'x-download-content-type' => $this->mimeType,
        'x-download-content-length' => $this->size,
        'expect' => '',
      );
      $this->request->setRequestHeaders($headers);
    }

    $response = $this->client->getIo()->makeRequest($this->request);
    $location = $response->getResponseHeader('location');
    $code = $response->getResponseHttpCode();

    if (200 == $code && true == $location) {
      return $location;
    }
    throw new Google_Exception("Failed to start the resumable download");
  }
}
```

Please try to resolve my problem.
Thank You,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem...
But with the minor bug... My api is not able to fetch other than .jpg file. It can't fetch even .jpeg... Please resolve this... Otherwise all is working fine...
Here is the new index.php file.

index.php

```
    <?php
    /*
     * Copyright 2011 Google Inc.
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     * You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     * limitations under the License.
     */

    include_once "templates/base.php";
    session_start();

    set_include_path("src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
    require_once 'Google/Client.php';
    require_once 'Google/Http/MediaFileDownload.php';
    require_once 'Google/Service/Drive.php';

    /************************************************
      ATTENTION: Fill in these values! Make sure
      the redirect URI is to this page, e.g:
      http://localhost:8080/fileupload.php
     ************************************************/
    $client_id = 'Your_Client_Id';
    $client_secret = 'Your_Client_Secret';
    $redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/MyApi/Google-Drive';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($client_id);
    $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
    $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['download_token']);
    }

    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['download_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['download_token']) && $_SESSION['download_token']) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['download_token']);
        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            unset($_SESSION['download_token']);
        }
    } else {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    }

    /********************************************************
      If we're signed in then lets try to download our file.
     ********************************************************/
    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    // This is downloading a file directly, with no metadata associated.
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $result = $service->files->listFiles(
        $file,
        array('downloadType' => 'media')
    );
}
echo pageHeader("File Download - Downloading a Photo");
if(
        $client_id == '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>' ||
        $client_secret == '<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>' ||
        $redirect_uri == '<YOUR_REDIRECT_URI>'
    ) {
    echo missingClientSecretsWarning();
}
?>
<div>
    <?php if (isset($authUrl)): ?>
    <a class='login' href='<?php echo $authUrl; ?>'>Log In To Your Google Account!</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<br>Result:<br><pre>
<?php print_r($result)?>
</pre><br><br>
<?php
    if (isset($result)){
        $i=0;
        echo "Image Path = ".$result['modelData']['items'][$i]['thumbnailLink']."<br>";
        foreach ($result as $key => $value){
            if(strcmp($result['modelData']['items'][$i]['mimeType'],'image/')){
                echo "Entered if cond";
?>
                <div>
                    <img src="<?php echo $result['modelData']['items'][$i]['thumbnailLink'];?>">
                </div>
<?php
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
?>
```